Scope of utility classes. What rules of thumb should I generally follow?
In your opinion, where do these utility methods belong?
    public static <T> List<T> itemsOf(JComboBox<T> comboBox) {
        ComboBoxModel<T> model = comboBox.getModel();
        List<T> items = IntStream.range(0, model.getSize())
                .mapToObj(model::getElementAt)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        return items;
    }

    public static <T> void refill(JComboBox<? super T> combo, Collection<? extends T> items) {
        combo.removeAllItems();
        items.forEach(combo::addItem);
    }

Is creating a whole separate utility class for dealing with JComboBox¹ too much, in your view? On the other hand, creating a utility for all JComponents may be, on the contrary, too broad.
It got me thinking in general: how do you set a scope for your utility? Is there some general guidance built over decades of production development? I'm sure there is. Once your utility class goes into the wild, it may be hard, if possible, to adjust its scope and rename it. So careful thinking is appropriate.
¹ Those are types belonging to Swing, Java's GUI library

In C#, I would probably make this an extension method for JComboBox, placed in a class JComboBoxExtensions.

@DocBrown I agree with your implication that such methods should be available in the combo class itself. However, we use plain JComboBoxes throughout our code. The class doesn't expose such methods

You are overinterpreting what I wrote.

Having a separate util class for combo box makes sense in my opinion, something like JComboBoxUtils. Other approach is to inherit JComboBox and add this methods as additions class MyComboBox extends JComboBox.

Whatever you do, you will need a class where the methods have to stay. If they are only used in one place, let's say in a class A, it makes sense to start with placing them there as private methods, but as soon as you need them in more than one place, lets say in classes A and B, it it better to use a separate class for them, one with a name which makes it easy to make these utility function (re-)discoverable at a later point in time.
Since these two functions might be seen as extensions to a JComboBox, things are easy. I would probably choose a name related to that class name, like JComboBoxExt, ExtJComboBox, or JComboBoxExtensions, or something like that, whatever your team prefers. There is no universally agreed standard for this, but it is definitely not an uncommon way of naming things. Even if those two functions stay the only two extensions of a JComboBox, does it hurt? On the other hand, using JComponent (the base class of JComboBox) and a related JComponentExt class as an "anchor" for all utility functions for all of JComponent's ~30 subclasses bears a certain risk to become a catch-all grave where you have trouble to find what you are looking for in a few months from now.
Naming gets a lot harder when you have utilities which cannot be seen that easily as an extension of an existing class. Here, the only recommendation I can give you is - use your best judgement, and ask a member of your team for a review. Your team may have their own conventions for utilities, maybe historically grown, we don't know, and mixing up some existing (maybe suboptimal) standard with some new conventions has a certain potential to makes things worse, not better, in case the old standard is not fully replaced by a new one.

The General rule with utility classes is "don't make them"
In your particular example we can get rid of the need for itemsOf by holding onto the list of items you add to the combobox and referencing that, rather than passing the combobox itself and extracting the list. Which I feel may be a mistake.
With refill, I would just use the two commands as needed.
The reason to avoid utility classes is that they multiply themselves and become a shared dependency, coupling all your code together. You end up with a large "helper" library which is used everywhere and which is very high risk to change.
Say for example I find that refill is slow on large lists. I change it to simply replace the combo box with a new one, constructed with the passed in list.
This fixes my LargeList app. But later TinyApp updates its dependencies and breaks because it needs the combobox to persist.
Functions that are used generically everywhere need to be held to a higher standard than code which is specific to a single use. Which makes them harder to write and maintain.

I do quite a bit of Kotlin on the JVM, so in Kotlin I would consider the correct solution to be an Extension Function, after doing this, the API now appears to directly implement the additional utility/extension functions.
I believe some third party libraries provide byte code manipulation to provide extension functions (Lombok for example), however I don't need/use them (due to using Kotlin), so I can't say what the pros or cons of this approach would be.
If you want to stick with vanilla Java, you probably have to settle for one of the following three choices:

Create static methods in a utility class.
Create a new class that extends JComboBox that provides the additional methods.
Use an adapter pattern - a class that takes the JComboBox in it's constructor, to provide the utility functions.

Static Methods
This is pretty much par for the course - you will find many code bases that just throw their utility functions in a class.
I would suggest giving it some thought, with respect to how you layout your classes, what functions you put in which classes and how you document / promote it.
The main problem with this approach is that it is to easy to forgot that a given method exists, in some random class so you end up with multiple people implementing the same function in different classes.
Extend JComboBox
The main disadvantage of this approach is that you have to change your UI construction logic - each UI has to be constructed with the extended versions of the classes.
You also burn your single inheritance, however that may not be so much of a problem in this case, since you probably want to collect all utility functions together, so they are all available on all JComboBoxes
The two advantages of this approach are that:

The utility methods are directly callable on the class.
Your IDE will probably complete method names for you.

Adapter Pattern
Doesn't really have a lot of value unless you also proxy the original interfaces of the JComboBox, if you do this, you are effectively encapsulating the original object and exposing a similar set of interfaces - so you can use the adapter/composite in place of the original.
This has similar advantages to extending JComboBox except that:

You don't have to burn your single inheritance.
You don't need to change the UI construction logic.

The disadvantage is that, you will need to keep updating your classes, each time the interfaces you are proxying are updated.
